# Extra white space at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I have some extra space appearing at the bottom of a website and not sure how. Does anyone know what is causing this?

http://192.99.37.125/~maggiemcflys/our-story/

The goal is to remove the extra white space.

Comment: Please see How to ask on Stack OverFlow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to the following:-

```
#content {
    bottom: -5px;
    padding: 0 10% 0 30%;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Ive added bottom: -5px to remove the space.

The issue is to do with the follow line of code:-

```
<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div>
```

Its causing the white space.

specifically the following CSS:-

```
.ui-datepicker {
    margin: 5px auto 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this works, I feel like this is either an issue with jQuery UI's datepicker, or Gravity Forms.